# MythTV, and MySQL 5.7 vs MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, 21.04, mythtv

I have MythTV 3.1 installed. Haven't used it for a while, so I thought that I would play with it for a bit.

Its database currently uses MySQL 5.7.

I noticed that for Ubuntu 21.04, MySQL 8.0 seems to be the norm. Don't know why it wouldn't have gotten upgraded when I went from 20.10 to 21.04.

Is it safe to install MySQL 8.0 (it'll automatically remove MySQL 5.7)?

**Update**: Changed reference of MySQL 5.8 to MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it safe to install MySQL 5.8 (it'll automatically remove MySQL 5.7)?"

Yes, those 2 do not have a lot of differences.

There is also no real need to upgrade to 5.8 though so if you want to stick to 5.7 that is also an option.

Sidenote: MySQL 8 is another issue though; that one is fairly different to 5.*.

And as always do make a backup of your databases just to be sure you have an option to fall back on.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I Googled how to backup/restore SQL databases... and that looks like a whole lot of fun... not.

Comment: That is easy ;) command line `mysqldump -u {user} -p {db} > {db}.sql` for each database Do you have  **mysql workbench** installed? Problably quicker if you have more than 5 databases.

Comment: I have one main database for MythTV, but it seems there are 4-5 other MySQL databases used to track interface/config/performance/etc. I don't know if I need to backup those too. Yes, I do have MySQL Workbench installed.

Comment: https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Database_Backup_and_Restore ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, mythconverg_backup.pl runs automagically now, and keeps 5 copies of the backup .sql file. I looked at MySQL Workbench, and I didn't see a real obvious way to manually backup/restore databases. I see export/import, but I'm not sure that's it. Do you know any other way?

Answer (score 0):

apt will automatically hold back any upgrades if they will cause problems/ breakage with other programs. So, the fact that it would not upgrade should tell you that there will be a problem. That being said..you can force an upgrade, however if there is no need for the different features, why would you?

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!